# How to make BSON document splitable in Spark so it can be processed parallely?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, split, compression, bson

I am querying MongoDB from Spark program. it's returning BSON document. Since BSON is not a splittable format its processing it sequentially with only one executor even though it has multiple available.

One solution I came to know is to Split file using BSONSplitter API and then compress it to Lzo as it is a splittable format.
I don't want to save the file to disk i.e. write using .lzo format as I have to do some processing on that.
So my query is, is it possible to compress the BSON file/split into memory itself and then create a dataframe / RDD out of it and then process it in distributed manner.

or

There is altogether a different approach possible.

I am using Spark 1.6.
Please let me know if additional information is required.

Comment: Why do you want to split the BSON? Why cant' you parallelize the querying itself, say you divide you query into n partitions and these n partitions results go to different partitions. I think this is how MongoDB connector works. https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/

Comment: sure thanks! Let me try this and will let you know accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this using Mongospark.load with readconfig containing SamplePartitioner but still it is returning single doc which is not splittable hence spark is assigning only one task for processing this file. am I missing something, when you say "divide your query into n partitions...", did you mean manually create those many queries, hope not, could you kindly clarify?